# HELP : Have a terminal screen after Grub and booting on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows10.
Since 3 month, I use this configuration without any bug, but this morning, when I launch ubuntu from grub, no graphic interface appear just a terminal which ask me to type my login and my password.
After this, I can use the terminal like all of the terminal and acceeded to my file but I haven't graphic interface.

Does someone have a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try typing

```
sudo startx
```

As for the **lsb_release: not found** I can't be sure this is related to the missing desktop but try

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-release
```

So you seem to have everything now so type

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

And is you were previously running a different desktop let's see by typing

```
ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
```

Comment: Nervermind ! It work, after reboot my pc and go again on ubuntu, my desktop was like before !!!!
Thank really a lot

Answer (score 0):

I did :
`sudo apt-get install lsb-release`

And then reboot and `sudo startx`

Here the output :
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXczJ.jpg)

EDIT :
I don't really know what I did but after trying to do :

```
sudo systemctl status gdm3
startx
```

The output was much better :

[Update Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpWQM.jpg)

EDIT2 : @darth_epoxy

after

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
startx
```

Ubuntu desktop start but it's not the default desktop ...
[Screen desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih6DI.jpg)